# Nutch + Solr - Clean takes a very long time to complete

Tags: hadoop, solr, web-crawler, search-engine, nutch

I'm building a search engine using Apache Nutch + Solr.

I'm using the `bin/crawl` script for the crawling + indexing. I've indexed about 50,000 documents, and now, on every iteration, the `cleaning phase` takes about **6 mins** to complete (while the phases prior to it take about **2 mins**).

When looking in the `hadoop.log` file, I can see that on every iteration, the total number of deleted documents in the `indexer.CleaningJob` phase increases (the current number is 11,700 deleted documents).

Why does it take such a long time to complete, and what can I do to solve this problem?

I will appreciate any help I can get!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an asymmetry which documents are selected for indexing resp. cleaning:

- during each crawl cycle only documents from the last segment are indexed/updated because content (parsed data and text) are required
- however, all 404s, duplicates, redirects, etc. contained in the CrawlDb are deleted from the index. While 404s and redirects could be also deleted using the segments based on the HTTP response status, some jobs modify the status in the CrawlDb (e.g., detecting duplicates based on the content signature).

Over time the CrawlDb grows and becomes much larger than a single segment. That slows down the cleaning job. You could modify the bin/crawl script to do the deletions not every cycle.